# C++ Word-Number to int

Tags: c++

I'm developing a program that makes basic calculations using words instead of numbers. E.g. five + two would output seven.

The program becomes more complex, taking input such as two_hundred_one + five_thousand_six
(201 + 5006)

Through operator overloading methods, I split each number and assign it to it's own array index.

two would be [0], hundred is [1], and one is [2]. Then the array recycles for 5006.

My problem is, to perform the actual calculation, I need to convert the words stored in the array to actual integers.

I have const string arrays such as this as a library of the words:

```
const string units[] = { "", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

const string teens[] = { "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };

const string tens[] = { "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };
```

If my 'token' array has stored in it two hundred one in index 0, 1, and 2, I'm not sure what the best way to convert these to ints would involve.

Comment: If all you want is to turn an individual number-word into an integer, then it's easy enough.  Just scan through those arrays in a for loop until you get a match.  Or you can use a map, as Jesse recommends.   Parsing a whole number-phrase like "thirty two thousand, three hundred and forty two" is more tricky.  Which problem do you want help with?

Comment: I've tried lot's of if statements but what I find the hardest is the teen numbers

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala I reckon I need help with the multiple word numbers.

Comment: You might find it useful to look at answers to Project Euler question 17, which is concerned with this: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bproject-euler%5D+17  , http://projecteuler.net/problem=17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the trick for me was to parse the tokens backwards, rather than forwards. And to maintain a scale factor as you move back through the tokens. For each token you either add to the current value (scaled by the current value of the scalefactor) or adjust the scalefactor, depending on which token you encounter.

Here's my implementation (some bits are not included, and you'd need to add a little logic to handle millions).

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <assert.h>

int tokens_to_int( const std::vector<std::string> &s )
{
  int scale = 1;
  int rv=0;
  for(
      std::vector<std::string>::const_reverse_iterator it = s.rbegin();
      it!=s.rend();
      ++it
     )
  {
    std::string cw = *it;
    //Things that add to the current value
    if( cw == "one" )   { rv += 1 * scale; }
    if( cw == "two" )   { rv += 2 * scale; }
    if( cw == "three" ) { rv += 3 * scale; }
    if( cw == "four" )  { rv += 4 * scale; }
    // ...
    if( cw == "nine" )   { rv += 9 * scale; }
    if( cw == "ten" )    { rv += 10 * scale; }

    // Teens
    if( cw == "eleven" )  { rv += 11 * scale; }
    if( cw == "twelve" )  { rv += 12 * scale; }
    // ...
    if( cw == "nineteen" )  { rv += 19 * scale; }

    // Multiples of 10
    if( cw == "twenty" )    { rv += 20 * scale; }
    if( cw == "thirty" )    { rv += 30 * scale; }
    if( cw == "fourty" )    { rv += 40 * scale; }
    // ...
    if( cw == "ninety" )    { rv += 90 * scale; }

    //Things that effect scale for following entries
    if( cw == "hundred" ) { scale *= 100; }
    if( cw == "thousand" ) { if( scale==100) { scale=1000; } else { scale*=1000; } }
  }

  return rv;
}

template<typename T>
struct as_vec
{
  as_vec<T>& operator()(const T & t )
  {
    v.push_back(t);
    return *this;
  }

  std::vector<T> build() { return v; }

  std::vector<T> v;
};

int main()
{
  assert(421 == tokens_to_int( as_vec<std::string>()("four")("hundred")("twenty")("one").build() ) );
  assert(422 == tokens_to_int( as_vec<std::string>()("four")("hundred")("twenty")("two").build() ) );
  assert(11000 == tokens_to_int( as_vec<std::string>()("eleven")("thousand").build() ) );
  assert(21201 == tokens_to_int( as_vec<std::string>()("twenty")("one")("thousand")("two")("hundred")("one").build() ) );
  assert(100001 == tokens_to_int( as_vec<std::string>()("one")("hundred")("thousand")("one").build() ) );
  assert(101000 == tokens_to_int( as_vec<std::string>()("one")("hundred")("one")("thousand").build() ) );
  assert(411201 == tokens_to_int( as_vec<std::string>()("four")("hundred")("eleven")("thousand")("two")("hundred")("one").build() ) );
  assert(999999 == tokens_to_int( as_vec<std::string>()("nine")("hundred")("ninety")("nine")("thousand")("nine")("hundred")("ninety")("nine").build() ) );
}
```

Comment: This looks nice, much cleaner than what I was trying (once you accept the need to pre-tokenize).   The only concern is detecting nonsense like "thousand two nineteen".

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much you saved me some really precious hours of work!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jesse about using the map to map values to your arrays, and from that point you'll be able to do something like:

```
mymap["two"] * mymap["hundred"] + mymap["one"]
```

of course you'll have to be careful about cases like "five hundred two thousand fifty seven" in which case you'll have to check for a special case other than the teens one:

```
const string temp[] = {"five","hundred","two","thousand","fifty","seven"};

int handleThree(int start)  {
    if( mymap[temp[start+ 3]] > 100) //check for special case, in which case you handle 4 words instead of three
       return (myap[temp[start]] * mymap[temp[start+1]] + mymap[temp[start+2]]) * mymap[temp[start+3]];
    else
       return mymap[temp[start]] * mymap[temp[start+1]] + handleTwo(start+2)
}

int handleTwo(int start) {
    if(mymap[temp[start]] / 10 == 1) //check if it's a teen, return teen value
       return mymap[temp[start]]
    if(mymap[temp[start+1]] > 90) //check for another special case, "five thousand one hundred and fifty seven", for example should use this case
       return mymap[temp[start]] * mymap[temp[start+1]]
    else
       return mymap[temp[start]] + mymap[temp[start+1]];
}
```

of course, there are some more cases you will have to watch out for ("five hundred sixty two thousand thirteen" for example), but it'd be stealing your fun and learning experience to help you handle such cases, but I believe this should be enough to get you started.

Also, I'm not the best at C++, so I apologize for any problems with my code if you should find them, but from my testing this worked with the main loop I wrote (I'll provide it if necessary but I think it'd benefit you to write that yourself)